# Querying collection using array meteor js

Tags: arrays, mongodb, meteor, publish-subscribe, meteor-blaze

I have this weird scenario which I do not know what the problem is exactly. While troubleshooting I found out that the subscription is published and subscribed to because it's printed on the console. When I executed this on Firefox console it displayed this error `SyntaxError: missing : after property id [Learn More]`. I don't know what the syntax error is as the same code works on other files. 
If I remove `fetch()` function from it it displayed 2 obects being published. This means the publish and sbscription is working. What am I to do right?
This is the event function

```
students(){
    let myslug = trimInput(Session.get('ReceivedSlug'));
    if (myslug) {
        let mySchoolDoc = SchoolDb.findOne({slug: myslug});
        if (mySchoolDoc) {
            let arrayModuleSchool = StudentSchool.find({schoolId: mySchoolDoc._id});
            if (arrayModuleSchool) {
                var arrayStudentIds = [];
                arrayModuleSchool.forEach(function(studentSchool){
                   arrayStudentIds.push(studentSchool.studentId);
                });
                let subReadiness = SchoolStudents.find({ _id: {$in: arrayStudentIds}}).fetch();
                if (subReadiness) {
                    console.log('before readiness --- ' +arrayStudentIds);
                    console.log('after seting --- ' +subReadiness);
                   return subReadiness;
                } 
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

This is the publish function

```
Meteor.publish('PaginatedStudents', function (skipCount) {
  check(skipCount, Number);
    user = Meteor.users.findOne({_id:this.userId})
    if(user) {
        if(user.emails[0].verified) {
           return SchoolStudents.find({userId: this.userId}, {limit: 2, skip: skipCount});
        } else {
           throw new Meteor.Error('Not authorized');
           return false;
        }
     }
});
```

Tracker to rerun when things changes

```
Session.setDefault('skip', 0);
Tracker.autorun(function () {
    Meteor.subscribe('PaginatedStudents', Session.get('skip'));
});
```

Comment: And what is `arrayStudentIds` value?

Comment: It printed out the _ids of the students. That's working fine.

Comment: So what is the error line?

Comment: `SyntaxError: missing : after property id [Learn More]` This is the error it gives when ran from Firefox console.

Comment: When ran _what_ from Firefox console?

Comment: `SchoolStudents.find({ _id: {$in: arrayStudentIds}}).fetch()` This is what I ran from Firefox console and it returned the error posted above.

Comment: I just ran this line in my Firefox and there was no any error. I'm afraid it would be impossible to help you without additional information. [[screenshot](https://d3vv6lp55qjaqc.cloudfront.net/items/3X3b0O1Q3o3N1u2m460S/Screen%20Shot%202017-09-30%20at%203.19.30%20PM.png)]

Comment: Sorry how did you ran it? `SchoolStudents.find({ _id: {$in: "erffggg355gfr","44554dfgghrr"}}).fetch()` . This is exactly the command I ran on Firefox. Hope it's the right way?

Comment: Oh... you forgot to surround your ids with `[` and `]`. It should be `... { $in: [ "erffggg355gfr","44554dfgghrr" ] } ...`

Comment: Thanks boss. Understood. I'll give it a shot again.

Comment: When I executed this not long I got an empty array:  `SchoolStudents.find({ _id: {$in: ["erffggg355gfr","44554dfgghrr"]}}).fetch() .` I'm yet to understand the reason.

Comment: Perhaps, you don't have documents with those ids.

Comment: There are documents. I'm yet to understand the reason.

Comment: Well, we can _chat_ here for a long time with no result, or you can add all relevant information to your question, so it would help us to help you.

Comment: You should delete this question and start over with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It's not at all clear what your real problem is.